# Questions about Boolean logic

Tags: number-theory, logic, boolean-algebra

1. Is there a systematic way to show that a set of Boolean operators is complete? Or is it more of an art than a science?
2. Similarly, is there a systematic way to convert any Boolean expression in terms of said operators? For example if I am only allowed to use NAND, etc.

Comment: 1) You could make a Post's test. If there are exist self dual function, linear function, monotone function and one-save/zero-save function.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_lattice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post's theorem on functional completeness gives a complete answer to this question (it tells you how to recognise functionally complete sets and the proof, at least in principle, gives a systematic approach to representing a given boolean function in terms of a given complete set of connectives). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_lattice.

For example, consider the operation NAND which I will write $\uparrow$. Post's theorem tells you that $\{\uparrow\}$ it is functionally complete (because it is not monotonic, affine, etc.). Once you know that, it is worth working by trial and error to see how to represent other standard operations using $\uparrow$: you will find that $\lnot A$ is $A \uparrow A$ and $A \lor B$ is $\lnot A \uparrow \lnot B$. (This now gives a direct proof that $\{\uparrow\}$ is functionally complete assuming that you already know that $\{\lnot, \lor\}$ is functionally complete.)

Comment: Is there a plain English way to explain Post's lattice? I read the Wiki but don't understand how to use it in the context I was explaining earlier.

Comment: Post's theorem makes it easy to recognise functionally complete sets (see the first Wikipedia link). Once you know how to recognise functionally complete sets, then you can systematically convert an arbitrary boolean expression into one generated by a given functionally complete set of operators by enumerating  expressions and testing for equivalence.

Comment: Are you saying it is literally brute force / guess and check by "enumerating and testing"?

Comment: I am saying that Post's theorem guarantees that the brute force approach will work if you first test your set of operations for functional completeness.  If you want something more efficient, then you need to refine your question.

Comment: Can you give an example? For example is {OR, NAND} complete / how can we prove one way or the other? What about writing something like (a->b)->b using only NAND?

Comment: I've added an example to the question which should help with this. Particularly if you note that $(a \to b) \to b)$ is logically equivalent to $a \lor b$.